# Using a given value to search the Database

Tags: .net, vb.net

Okay guys so here is a tricky one(for me anyway). I have a database where I have certain customers and certain sums of the orders they have. I am writing a script while also using DataOleDb so that I can access this Orders database, which is just a simple Access Database I created. Basically I want the user to insert an ID into a textbox, and then press a button. Afterwards, that button will search for the Customer with said ID and show the user the value of that guy's Order.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Dim dataFile = "C:\users\admin\Desktop\SAD.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    conn.Open()

    'Dim q = "SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='Y' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='N' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END type_of_client FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = '+TextBox2.text+'"
    Dim q = "SELECT OrderValue FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID=" + TextBox2.Text
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(q, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(q, conn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

The problem is I am still a beginner when it comes to using parameterized commands in .NET. I've used them in C# but they are quite different there. So my SELECT query has worked, but how can I use the result of what it extracted from my database to show it someplace. I mean the OrderValue after all was the information he was searching for in the first place.

Excuse the commented script line, that is actually my overall mission, to check if the client paid their fee or not so I can see if he is a bad or good customer, but baby steps.

Comment: Search for some examples how to use a OleDbDataReader or OleDbDataAdapter. You don't need both.

Comment: "I've used them in C# but they are quite different there" - parameterized commands are absolutely 100% identical between VB.NET and C#; if you've used them in C#: you should basically do *exactly what you did there*; your current code is *actively dangerous* re SQL injection. Tip: consider using Dapper or similar - it will make your data access code *much* simpler and safer.

Comment: Side note: if you're reading exactly one row and one column, `ExecuteScalar` is a lot simpler : it reads the first column of the first row of the first grid - probably exactly what you want.

Comment: @MarcGravell In C# I am used to writing stuff like WHERE CustomerID=@givenValue inside the statement. And afterwards I would just go like q.Parameters.AddWithValue("givenValue", TextBox1.Text). I am guessing that the logic of it is probably the same, but for a newbie like me, seeing them side by side threw me for a loop.

Comment: *"I am guessing that the logic of it is probably the same"*. It's not that the logic is the same. It's that the code is the same. You could pretty much remove the semicolons from the C# code and you'd have the VB code.

Answer (score 0):

Loop dr.read to loop the DataReader, and use dr.item(0) as you do have only have one value in your query to call out the value from the reader.

The example below uses "console.writeline" to call out the value from the reader.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Dim dataFile = "C:\users\admin\Desktop\SAD.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    conn.Open()

    Dim q = "SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='Y' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='N' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END type_of_client FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = '+TextBox2.text+'"
    Dim q = "SELECT OrderValue FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID=" + TextBox2.Text
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(q, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(q, conn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.read) 
    Console.writeline(dr.item(0))
    loop 
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Although I think the question owner do only wish to know how to get value from the DataReader
Since many experts do mention the issue of avoiding the SQL Injection.
let us do a code with SQL Parameter which is SQL injection-free.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
    Dim dataFile = "C:\users\admin\Desktop\SAD.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    conn.Open()

    'Dim q = "SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='Y' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) > SUM(CASE WHEN Payment='N' THEN OrderValue ELSE 0 END) THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END type_of_client FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = @customerid"
    Dim q = "SELECT OrderValue FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID= @customerid"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(q, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While (dr.read) 
         Console.writeline(dr.item(0))
    loop 
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: (and leaves in that *horrible* SQL injection hole)

Comment: @MarcGravell I know SQL injection is a very dangerous thing. Fortunately, now I am just trying to understand the basics so I don't mind it. I know it's better off to learn the best way from the beginning rather than muddle through later, but that will have to do for now. Thanks anyway for your suggestions!

Comment: There are a lot of problems in this answer that are not addressed. Sql Injection is the main one (albeit MS-Access is not prone to the simple ones because it doesn't support batch statements) but then we have also disposable objects not disposed, connectionstring hard-coded. Useless OleDbDataAdapter. Building a reader when a simple ExecuteScalar is enough. So, in my opinion this answer while giving the solution about the OleDbDataReader is not a good answer.